# RoutedEvents Combobox not Firing

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-events

Hi could some kind person help.  I have two user controls. One with a textbox, the other with a Combobox.  The Main window will perform calculation routine as soon as combos and textboxes are modified.
The Textbox version works, the ComboBox doesn't.  The only difference I can see is
Textbox uses TextChangedEventArgs
whereas
Combobox uses System.EventArgs

Any ideas?
Thanks

```
// UserControl - with TextBox

public event RoutedEventHandler ucTextChanged;

        private void OnTextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ucTextChanged != null)
            {
                ucTextChanged(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
            }
        }

       private void txtValue_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            OnTextChanged(sender, e);
        }

// UserControl - ComboBox

      public event RoutedEventHandler ucComboChanged;


        private void OnComboChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ucComboChanged != null)
            {
                ucComboChanged(this, new RoutedEventArgs());
            }
        }

      private void ucCombo_DropDownClosed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        OnComboChanged(sender, e);      
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the event SelectionChanged of the ComboBox ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.combobox.onselectionchanged )

XAML:

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="ucCombo_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
```

C#:

```
    private void ucCombo_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // your code here...
        OnComboChanged(sender, e);
    }
```

Comment: The combo is in a UserControl, so there needs to be some connection from the (many) user controls, to the main form.  I seem to have something working, adding these on both the UserControl and Main form.

            ucCombo.AddHandler(ComboBox.KeyUpEvent,
              new RoutedEventHandler(ComboHandler));

            ucCombo.AddHandler(ComboBox.SelectionChangedEvent,
            new RoutedEventHandler(ComboHandler));